# How to use Dictionary.Values.Where <TSource> (Func<TSource,bool> predicate) to find needed values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have dictionary, like

```
Dictionary<string, bool> accValues = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
```

And I want to get bool value for specific key. I can do it via foreach, like

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> keypair in accValues)
            {
                if (keypair.Key == "SomeString")
                {
                    return keypair.Value;
                }
            }
```

But how is it possible to realize using Where function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why iterate over every key/value pair?
Use

```
accValues["SomeString"]
```

or, if you don't want an exception to be thrown when no such key exists in the dictionary:

```
accValue.TryGetValue("SomeString", out boolValue)
```

if you want to find a value for a key that matches some arbitrary predicate, you can use a statement like this:

```
accValues.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "SomeString").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```